# Using multiple wildcards within iterator of ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, feature-class, iterator, wildcard

I would like to know if it is possible to use multiple wildcards to select specific shapefiles when using the Iterate Feature Classes tool in ArcGIS ModelBuilder.

I use this to select all shapes beginning with T but wonder how I would ask the iterator to select shapes beginning with R,S & T, for example.

[image: Iterate Feature Classes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this I would chain three submodels together.

Each submodel will use [Iterate Feature Classes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00400000000r000000) configured using the wildcard with a different letter (R, S, then T).

The use of submodels is needed because of the "one iterator per model" restriction.

There is a help page available on [Integrating a model within a model](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w0000007p000000) but its examples all look to be more complicated than what you are trying to do.  Nevertheless, it may be worth quickly reviewing for future reference.