# Iterate over feature classes with multiple wildcards

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, modelbuilder, iterator, wildcard

[image]Is there a way how to iterate over feature classes in Model Builder in ArcGIS 10.3 using a number of different wildcards?

The wildcards I want to use are strings in the middle of the feature class names. If it was just one wildcard, I would use (asterisk)IVORY(asterisk) and it would do the trick but with a number of different ones it doesn’t work. I tried to type “*IVORY* or *CAMEROON*” and also “*IVORY*,*CAMEROON*” but neither worked.

It would probably be possible to do it creating submodels but when I have a large number of wildcards it would be too much work so I'm looking for a different solution.

Feature class names examples: "feature_class_1_NA300002_IVORY_COAST_AUS15" and "feature_class_2_NA300002_CAMEROON_MAR15" etc.

If possible, I would like to do it without the need to use a scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to if the wildcards that you are using can work is no.

You can however use a [precondition](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-using-precondition.htm) to control the workflow. So the iterator lets everything through and then you say continue if it has ivory/cameroon.

The model is simply this:

[image: Model]

The Calculate Value tool is a precondition to the rest of the workflow, in this case simply adding a field.

The Calculate Value tool is set up as shown below:

[image: Calculate Value tool]

*Please note indentation is critical in python!*

An alternative solution is discussed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67535/using-multiple-wildcards-within-iterator-of-arcgis-modelbuilder?rq=1).